# Is there a way to UPDATE column values based another column's value?

Tags: mysql

Part 1 of my SQL task involves restructuring data. The jist of my task is as follows: Based on the event_type, if it is "begin" I am trying to use that "time" to find it's stopping time (in another row) and add it to a column (event_end) on the same row as the start time so that all the data for an event sits nicely in one row.

```
pID  customerID  locationID  event_type  time   event_end (new row)
1     1           a          begin       12.45
2     2           a          begin       11.10
3     1           a          stop        1.30
4     2           b          begin       9.45
5     3           b          stop        8.78
```

I would like to add another column (event_end), and have event_end = the minimum value of event_start IF event_start = 'stop', IF locationID = locationID, and IF customerID = customerID. The final step would be to delete all event_start 'begin' rows.

I have tried UPDATE SET WHERE sequences, and a little bit of CASE, but my issue is that I cannot wrap my head around how to perform this without a loop like VBA. The following is my best stab at it:

```
UPDATE table
SET event_end = MIN(time)
  WHERE event_type = 'stop'
  WHERE customerid = customerid
  WHERE locationid = locationid
  WHERE time > time

SELECT * 
FROM table
```

I'm hoping to have a table with all event data in one row, not spread out over multiple rows. If this is a handful, I appologize but am thankful in advance.
Thanks

Comment: What are you using, MS Access or MySQL? Why did you label "case"? Please select the appropriate labels only (after reading what the label represents). And adjust your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem Statement**:

- Add `event_end` as an extra attribute to the existing row, data will be populated based on `customer_id, location_id`.
- We will populate data in `event_end` to all events which have event type as `begin`
- Data would be picked from rows which have the same `customer_id, location_id` but event type as `stop`.
- Finally, we will remove all events with type `stop`.

**Solution**: Consider your table name is `customer_events` and will use `self join` concept for the same.

- First, identify which records needs to be updated. We can use a `SELECT` query to identify such records.
- `c1` table will represent rows with `begin` event type.
- `c2` table will represent rows with `stop` event type.

```
SELECT *
FROM customer_events c1
LEFT JOIN customer_events c2 ON c1.customerID = c2.customerID AND c1.locationID = c2.locationID AND c1.event_type = 'begin' AND c2.event_type = 'stop'
WHERE c1.event_type = 'begin';  -- As we want to populate data in events with value as `begin`
```

- Write a query to update the records.

```
UPDATE customer_events c1
LEFT JOIN customer_events c2 ON c1.customerID = c2.customerID AND c1.locationID = c2.locationID AND c1.event_type = 'begin' AND c2.event_type = 'stop'
SET c1.event_end = c2.`time`          
WHERE c1.event_type = 'begin';
```

- Now every record with event type as `begin` has either value in `event_end` column or it would be null if no records match as `stop` event.
- For rows with event type as `stop`, either they are mapped with some row with event type as `begin` or some are not mapped. In both cases, we don't want to keep them. To remove all records with event type as `stop`.

```
DELETE FROM customer_events
WHERE event_type = 'stop';
```

Note: Don't run `DELETE` statement unless you are sure that this solution will work for you.

**Updated**: We can have multiple records of `begin & stop` events for single customer & location.

```
Sample Input:
| pID | customerID* | *locationID* | *event_type* | *time* | *event_end* |
| 1   | 1           | a            | begin        | 02:45:00  |          |
| 2   | 2           | a            | begin        | 03:10:00  |          |
| 3   | 1           | b            | begin        | 04:30:00  |          |
| 4   | 2           | b            | begin        | 05:45:00  |          |
| 5   | 2           | a            | stop         | 06:49:59  |          |
| 6   | 1           | a            | begin        | 07:38:00  |          |
| 7   | 3           | b            | begin        | 08:57:19  |          |
| 8   | 2           | b            | stop         | 09:57:43  |          |
| 9   | 3           | b            | stop         | 10:58:03  |          |
| 10  | 4           | a            | begin        | 11:58:34  |          |
| 11  | 1           | a            | stop         | 12:09:36  |          |
| 12  | 1           | b            | stop         | 13:09:50  |          |
| 13  | 1           | a            | stop         | 14:10:02  |          |
```

Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT 
       ce.*,
       IF(@c_id <> ce.customerId OR @l_id <> ce.locationID, @rank:= 1, @rank:= @rank + 1 ) as rank, 
        @c_id:= ce.customerId, 
        @l_id:= ce.locationID
    FROM customer_events ce, 
    (SELECT @c_id:= 0 c, @l_id:= '' l, @rank:= 0 r) AS t 
    WHERE event_type = 'begin'
    ORDER BY customerId, locationID, `time`) AS c1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
       ce.*,
       IF(@c_id <> ce.customerId OR @l_id <> ce.locationID, @rank:= 1, @rank:= @rank + 1 ) as rank, 
        @c_id:= ce.customerId, 
        @l_id:= ce.locationID
    FROM customer_events ce, 
    (SELECT @c_id:= 0 c, @l_id:= '' l, @rank:= 0 r) AS t 
    WHERE event_type = 'stop'
    ORDER BY customerId, locationID, `time`
) AS c2 ON c1.customerID = c2.customerID AND c1.locationID = c2.locationID AND c1.rank = c2.rank;

Output:
| pId | customerID| locationId| event_type| Start_Time|End_Id|  End_Time |
| 1   | 1         | a         | begin     | 02:45:00  | 11   | 12:09:36  |
| 6   | 1         | a         | begin     | 07:38:00  | 13   | 14:10:02  |
| 3   | 1         | b         | begin     | 04:30:00  | 12   | 13:09:50  |
| 2   | 2         | a         | begin     | 03:10:00  | 5    | 06:49:59  |
| 4   | 2         | b         | begin     | 05:45:00  | 8    | 09:57:43  |
| 7   | 3         | b         | begin     | 08:57:19  | 9    | 10:58:03  |
| 10  | 4         | a         | begin     | 11:58:34  |      |           |
```

**Update Statement**: Create two columns `end_pID` and `event_end` for migration.

```
UPDATE customer_events 
INNER JOIN (
SELECT c1.pId, c2.pID End_Id, c2.time AS End_Time
FROM (
    SELECT 
       ce.*,
       IF(@c_id <> ce.customerId OR @l_id <> ce.locationID, @rank:= 1, @rank:= @rank + 1 ) as rank, 
        @c_id:= ce.customerId, 
        @l_id:= ce.locationID
    FROM customer_events ce, 
    (SELECT @c_id:= 0 c, @l_id:= '' l, @rank:= 0 r) AS t 
    WHERE event_type = 'begin'
    ORDER BY customerId, locationID, `time`) AS c1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
       ce.*,
       IF(@c_id <> ce.customerId OR @l_id <> ce.locationID, @rank:= 1, @rank:= @rank + 1 ) as rank, 
        @c_id:= ce.customerId, 
        @l_id:= ce.locationID
    FROM customer_events ce, 
    (SELECT @c_id:= 0 c, @l_id:= '' l, @rank:= 0 r) AS t 
    WHERE event_type = 'stop'
    ORDER BY customerId, locationID, `time`
) AS c2 ON c1.customerID = c2.customerID AND c1.locationID = c2.locationID AND c1.rank = c2.rank) AS tt ON customer_events.pID = tt.pId
SET customer_events.end_pID = t.End_Id, customer_events.event_end = t.End_Time;
```

Finally, remove all events with `event_type = 'stop'`

Comment: I will try it again tonight after work, thank you!
There may be multiple records with the same customerID and LocationID, for example a customer may have 4 or 5 events at the same location, would this ensure that the correct end date is being pulled? I can't see anything in the code reflecting that, but I am a rookie :)

Comment: Sure, try it and if it works do accept the answer. If any issue, let me know:)

Comment: Whoops sorry I added an edit to my last comment there Jitendra

Comment: @Kyle, if there are multiple events for the same location and customer, it won't work. But think, how even you can determine which `end` event is for which `begin`. Because in such processes when one event fails, we will not be having `end` event for that. Let me know if I missed something.

Comment: So it may just be impossible eh? The data does not fail with the way it is set up and the small, controlled nature of the data collection... every    begin    has an    end    .

Comment: Would it be sequential? Like every time first `end` is of first `begin` and second `end` for second `begin` and so on..  for a given customer and location? If so, then we can try one more time:)

Comment: @Kyle, check the previous comment and let me know, so if required we can find a solution.

Comment: Sorry, Yes! it would be sequential, it would be jumbled. I.e. there may be other customers and location events between a customers begin and end, but there will never be two begins per customer and location before an end

Comment: @Kyle, finally I got it. Do verify and accept the answer. I am waiting for this. Let me know if you face any issue. :)

Comment: Btw nice question too, gonna do an upvote for that. :) You should include this multiple customer & locations and sequential events in the question itself to make it more clear.